# How do I remove redundant Primary Keys from a MYSqL Table?

Tags: mysql

Ihave been developing an app for some time. This involves entering and deleteing alot of useless data in the tables. Now that I want to go to production I want to get rid of all the data but also restore all the 'IDs' ( primary keys ) to 0 so that the live system can start fresh with sensible ID's like 1,2,3 etc.

Using MySQL and PHP / Codeigniter

Many Many Thanks for yoru help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally use [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) - this both removes the data and resets the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Note that MySQL will perform a row by row deletion if there is a foreign key relationship, which is quite convenient (compared to SQL Server).

Answer (score 2):

If your pk is autoincrement, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

Make sure table is empty before executing the query.